# SharePoint Server 2016 Central Administration Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, central-administration, tags

This error has been popping up for a few days at least.  I am not sure when it started since I rarely visit Central Administation. At most a month I will say.

Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'

In the logs:

```
Parse exception occured on original: Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'

Application error when access /default.aspx, Error=Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'.   at System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)     at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)     at System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)     at System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type& childType, Boolean defaultProperty)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText)

System.Web.HttpException: Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'.    at System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)     at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)     at System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)     at System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type& childType, Boolean defaultProperty)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateP

Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unknown server tag 'AdminControls:EndOfSupportNotificationBar'.     at System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)     at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)     at System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)     at System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, I...
```

Current BuildVersion is 16.0.4651.1000 according to get-spfarm | select buildversion

Is this something that can be patched?  Or is there some other issue?  We have also been having some issues with the search service which is in another post.

```
$spprod = Get-SPProduct
$spprod.Servers | select ServerName, Products, InstallStatus
```

results in a status of upgrade required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had installed a patch but not finished the process by running PSConfig. Once that got done the error went away.